# Vuex getter does not return current state value

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have an object inside the Vuex state with certain server details. The state, mutation and getter look like this:

```
// Code inside store/index.js of the nuxt application

const state = () => ({
  serverDetails: {}
})

const mutations = {
  SERVER_DETAILS(state, value) {
    Vue.set(state, 'serverDetails', value)
  }
}

const getters = {
  getServerDetails(state) {
    console.log('GETTER: get details')
    return state.serverDetails
  }
}

export { state, mutations, getters }
```

Those details are initialized in the browser via an axios Ajax call, which does `commit()` on completion, e.g.

```
commit('SERVER_DETAILS', data)
```

Now I try to access those details inside the browser console but get different results.
*Inside the browser console:*

```
Output in the console during initial page load:
  GETTER: get details

> $store.state.serverDetails.timezone
  Output: 7200

> $store.getters.getServerDetails.timezone
  Output: undefined

> $store.commit('SERVER_DETAILS', {timezone: 123})
> $store.state.serverDetails.timezone
  Output: 123

> $store.getters.getServerDetails.timezone
  Output: undefined
```

As the output `GETTER: get details` is only displayed once on page load it seems, that Vuex caches the getters response and does not even call thee getter function later. Not even after I manually trigger a `commit()`...

**Question:** Am I doing something wrong here? Why does the getter return an empty object, while directly accessing the state works?

Comment: How do you init your store?

Comment: @Styx it's a nuxt application; the above store/mutations/getters code is inside the folder 'store/index.js'. I've added the last line of the store/index.js file above

Comment: Try `state.serverDetails = { ...value }` in your mutation, instead of `Vue.set()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Though, this does not solve the actual problem (getter is not updated on commit) - this workaround forces Vuex to **re-initialize the entire state**.

I have added this code  in an axios ajax response handler, which occurs only once per session:

```
commit('SERVER_DETAILS', data)

$store.hotUpdate($store.state) // <<-- This line is new.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Vuex state wrong, it should be an object.

```
const state = {
  serverDetails: {},
}
```

Comment: I've also tried this, but the console tells me `'state' should be a method that returns an object in store/index.js` - also, the state itself is working. Only some getters do not reflect the actual state values when committing the Ajax response.